# Best way to edit nested object properties with individual react components?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am trying to create a React form/editable table which allows a user to edit an object with the following structure:

```
{ID, name, year, number, categories: [ {ID, name, options: [ {ID, name} ] } ] }
```

I have been trying to find an efficient and clean way to display data of this form, allow editing, and keep track of the edited data in some parent component. Editing the surface level properties was fairly easy (and I believe clean). I had an event handler creator that took in the parameter name and would change that parameter anytime the textfield value changed.

```
const [Obj, setObject] = useState({ID: "", name: "", categories: []})

function changeEventHandlerCreator(name) {
return event => {
  let edittedObject = Object.assign({}, Obj);
  edittedObject[name] = event.target.value;
  setObject(edittedObject);
};
```

}

When I tried to do a similar method with the nested categories/options properties, it got pretty messy. I made more event handler creators for the categories and the options:

```
function categoryChangeEventHandlerForCategory(category) {
  return event => {
    let edittedCategory = Object.assign({}, category);
    edittedCategory.categoryName = event.target.value;
    editCategory(edittedCategory, category);
  };
}

function optionChangeEventHandlerForOptionInCategory(option, category) {
  return event => {
    let edittedOption = Object.assign({}, option, {
      optionName: event.target.value
    });
    editOptionInCategory(edittedOption, option, category);
  };
} 

function editCategory(newCategory, oldCategory) {
  let edittedCourse = Object.assign({}, course);
  let edittedCategories = course.categories.map(category =>
    category.categoryID !== oldCategory.categoryID ? category : newCategory
  );
  edittedCourse.categories = edittedCategories;
  setCourse(edittedCourse);
}

function addOptionToCategory(category) {
  let edittedCategory = Object.assign({}, category);
  let option = {
    optionID: nextOptionIndexForCategory(category),
    optionName: "",
    expanded: false
  };
  edittedCategory.options = [option, ...category.options];
  edittedCategory.expanded = true;
  editCategory(edittedCategory, category);
}
```

I was able to take a slight shortcut here. I knew I was only going to edit one properties, the name of the category/option, so I didn't have to take care of editting multiple properties like I did for the main object which made this method easier. I then pass the category/category and option into the event handle creators to make sure that function specifically changes that category/option. This is done by keeping track of the ID. The event handler creators for the categories use the ID to know which category/option is being editted. This is in the editCategory function where it maps the current categories to a new array, but if the ID is the same as the category passed in, it returns the new category instead of the old one. Same goes for editting options.

These event handlers are passed to the edittor components like shown below:

```
<MainObjEdittor changeEventHandleCreator={changeEventHandlerCreator}/>
{Obj.categories.map(category =>
    <CategoryEdittor categoryChangeEventHandlerForCategory(category)/>
    {category.options.map(option =>
        <OptionEdittor optionChangeEventHandlerForOptionInCategory(option, category)/>
    )}
)}
```

My question is, is this is the best way of doing this? It doesn't feel like it is. My goal is just to be able to edit any property of any object within the main object. Also, if I realize now that I will need to edit more than just the name property of the categories and options, so this method wouldn't work (or it would just get more messy). What would be a good method to